# What's the algorithm for computing polynomial regression

Tags: statistics, polynomials, regression, least-squares

I'm looking for a way of doing polynomial regression myself (I mean without the help of Excel or other cool software like Mathematica, ...).

I've heard of algorithm doing that, like `Gauss-Newton Algorithm` and `Least Squares Algorithm`, but I couldn't find an easy/straightforward way of using these algorithms.
I'm just asking if there is a nice way of computing them following a step by step method, like for the linear regression.

Comment: Look up linear least squares.  If you are beyond that, then you may need to clarify the question. Of course there are easy, straightforward methods for everything, but in this case, beyond linear least squares you will be looking at writing code..

Comment: @Narlin I wasn't looking for doing it by hand, I meant that I wanted to code something myself

Comment: Here is a site with both code and explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083465/fast-efficient-least-squares-fit-algorithm-in-c

Comment: @Narlin the code is meant for linear regression, which I'm already able to code by myself. I'm looking for polynomial regression, as Excel does basically.

Comment: OK. Then what you are looking for is called non-linear least squares.  It isn't difficult, but a simple answer with an example is probably beyond the scope of these questions.  Wikipedia has a good write up. Look elsewhere for examples.

Comment: @Narlin I found on GitHub regression js which has a few algorithm for regression. I'm going to use them as an example for my code 

Answer (score 0):

It is linear least squares with a kernel built of monomials.

$${\bf c_o}=\min_{\bf c}\|{\bf \Phi c - d}\|_2^2$$

where

$${\bf\Phi} = [{\bf 1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^n}]$$

where the 1,x etc are column vectors with the values and $\bf c$ is a column vector linearly combining them together (the vector of coefficients) and $\bf d$ is the vector of data points to fit to (function values).